# Iterations over dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
       A   B  C  
0    Bob  10  2
1    Bob  11  8
2  Sarah  23 -2
3  Sarah  24  4
4   Jack  19 -4
5   Jack  21 -1
```

I want to get a new `df["Point"]` as follows:

- To "Bob" group: `df["Point"]` is the multiplication of *first B value* by *C values*. 10*2=20; 10*8=80.
- To "Sarah" group: `df["Point"]` is the multiplication of *first B value* by *C values*. 23*(-2)=(-46); 23*4=92.
- To "Jack" group: `df["Point"]` is the multiplication of *first B value* by *C values*. 19*(-4)=(-76); 19*(-1)=(-19).

I mean, I want to get:

```
       A   B  C  Point
0    Bob  10  2     20
1    Bob  11  8     80
2  Sarah  23 -2    -46
3  Sarah  24  4     92
4   Jack  19 -4    -76
5   Jack  21 -1    -19
```

After that, I want to do the following iteration:

```
results = {}

grouped = df.groupby("A")

for idx, group in grouped:
    if (group["Point"] > 50).any():
        results[idx] = group[group["Point"] > 50].head(1)
        print ("")
    else:
        results[idx] = group.tail(1)
        print ("")
    print(results[idx])
```

And get this `results`:

```
      A   B  C  Point
1   Bob  11  8     80

      A   B  C  Point
3 Sarah  23  4     92

      A   B  C  Point
5  Jack  21 -1    -19
```

I guess I have to do a double iteration but I don´t know how, or if it possible to do that in a different way.

Comment: Why is second `Sarah` group multiple by second value?

Comment: Ok. I´ve edited it. I think it would be right for me with the first Sarah value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first create new column by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `first` and multiple by `C` column:

```
df['point'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first').mul(df['C'])
print (df)
       A   B  C  point
0    Bob  10  2     20
1    Bob  11  8     80
2  Sarah  23 -2    -46
3  Sarah  24  4     92
4   Jack  19 -4    -76
5   Jack  21 -1    -19
```

And then filter first all rows by condition and get only first rows by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) - `keep='first'` is by default:

```
df1 = df[df['point'] > 50].drop_duplicates('A')
print (df1)
       A   B  C  point
1    Bob  11  8     80
3  Sarah  24  4     92
```

Then filter rows which are not in `df1.A` column by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and inverted condition by `~`, again [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with keep last rows only:

```
df2 = df[~df['A'].isin(df1['A'])].drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
print (df2)
      A   B  C  point
5  Jack  21 -1    -19
```

Last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `dict comprehension` for final `dictionary`:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('A')}
print (d)
{'Bob':      A   B  C  point
1  Bob  11  8     80, 'Jack':       A   B  C  point
5  Jack  21 -1    -19, 'Sarah':        A   B  C  point
3  Sarah  24  4     92}
```